# .append jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

The HTML which should be produced after manipulation:

```
<div class="comments_action_207">
   <div class="list_item_comments list_item_comments_207">
      <div class="comment_separator">text goes here</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

HTML before manipulation:

```
<div class="comments_action_207"></div>
<div class="list_item_comments list_item_comments_207"><div class="comment_separator">text goes here</div></div>
```

JavaScript which allows me to do the above manipulation is:

```
$(function() {
    $('.comments_action_207').click(function() {
        var num = this.className.split('_').pop();
        $('</div>',{'class':'list_item_comments list_item_comments_' + num})
            .append('<div class="comment_separator">text goes here</div>')
            .appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

I tested the JavaScript above and it works fine. But what I don't understand is why I don't have to pass an **opening div** tag as below. If I pass an opening div tag code does not work as I intend to.

```
$('<div></div>',{'class':'list_item_comments list_item_comments_' + num}).
```

If you can please explain it line by line so It's is easier for me to understand.

Comment: ...When it's by itself, it's still just `<div />`, it's a self-closing tag, since you dont have another tag following it to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<div>` doesn't close properly:

```
$('<div><div/>'
            ^
```

jQuery accepts `<div />`, `<div>` and `<div></div>`, but *nothing else* (i.e. no HTML attributes): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: Really? I'll have to add that in. Thanks!

Comment: sure it is: http://jsbin.com/omujik/1/edit and also: `<div/>` (without the space lol) +1

Comment: Actually it does accept the map containing HTML attributes...or am I misunderstanding your post?

Comment: @Dasun: `<div><div/>` is not valid HTML, while `<div></div>` is correct. I am sure you already know it. You just misplaced the `/` character. In other words: you **can** pass the opening div tag... you just need to do it right.

Comment: Oops that is a typo. I'm sorry about it.Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ...It will work

```
$('<div></div>',{'class':'list_item_comments list_item_comments_' + num})
```